# How are these statements of the Radon-Nikodym theorem the same

Tags: radon-nikodym

I am reading [An Informal Introduction to Stochastic Calculus with Applications](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9620#t=aboutBook) and I've come across this statement of the Radon-Nikodym theorem.

"Consider the probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal {F},P)$, and let $\mathcal {G}$ be a $\sigma$ field in $\mathcal {F}$. The for any random variable $X$ there is a $\mathcal {G}$ measurable random variable such that $Y$ such that

$\int_{A}XdP=\int_{A}YdP$
"

this occurs after some discussion of conditional probabilities.

How does this statement correspond to the more familiar

${\displaystyle \nu (A)=\int _{A}f\,d\mu ,}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $X$ has finite mean, $\nu (A)=\int_AXdP$ define a (real) measure $\nu$ and $\nu (A)=0$ whenever $P(A)=0$. So there exists $Y$ such that $\nu(A)=\int_A YdP$. [RNT applies to real (and complex) measures also].

Comment: I had to read this a few times but it does actually make sense.